# How these two different ORA errors (ORA-12899 & ORA- 01461) are linked together

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jdbc

When I insert string into the oracle table which is more than defined size of a varchar column it results in following ORA errors. First one 'ORA-12899' is pretty much understandable and give right message. But sometime in my application, for same reason I got different error which is ORA- 01461 and it says "ORA- 01461 - can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column tips". This error tells very different reason but I just have varchar column and inserting string with more than defined size. Not sure where the LONG value comes in picture. I found similar thing on this [link](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1396250600346332245) too.

```
ORA-12899 - Value too Large for Column
ORA- 01461 - can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column tips
```

Looks like second ORA error is reported with respect to oracle cache like mentioned in this [link](https://community.denodo.com/kb/view/document/ORA-01461:%20can%20bind%20a%20LONG%20value%20only%20for%20insert%20into%20a%20LONG%20column?category=Common%20Errors). Can somebody share thoughts what is the exact difference in both errors and why sometime I got either of them due to same reason? I should generally get same error if I insert string into varchar column with max size than defined.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is about the SIZE (e.g. number of characters) of insert value which means destination column is not enough wide for the insert value, but the second one is about to insert a value from a LONG datatype into different datatype.